# Nifi/Minifi: Failed because FlowFile had an "http.context.identifier" attribute of but could not find an HTTP Response Object for this identifier

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'm using `Nifi 1.7.0` to create a flow and then I convert it to `Minifi 0.5.0`. When I run the application, initially it runs well, but after some requests I'm getting 504 error (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE), with this error message in `minifi-app.log`:

```
Failed to respond to HTTP request because FlowFile had an "http.context.identifier" attribute of but could not find an HTTP Response Object for this identifier.
```

I am using the same `StandardHttpContextMap` controller service for processors `HandleHttpRequest` and `HandleHttpResponse`, and I have also increased the `Request Expiration` parameter.

It seems that this issue only occurres when I increase the number of threads. With just one thread, it runs without any errors.

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: I'm facing the same thing, Ricardo.  Did you happen to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The HandleHTTPRequest and HandleHTTPResponse need to use the same HTTP Context Service

Comment: Both processors are already using the same HTTP Context Service

Comment: Then you need to provide more infomation about your flow and configs - this is not enough information to go on.

Comment: I edited the question just now, with more informations about it